# Attach security group to NAT Gateway network interface in Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to attach a security group that I created to the network interface of my NAT Gateway.

This gives me the following error:

*you do not have permission to access the specified resource*

[image: error]

I don't know why, since I've created the security group exactly like the one in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#NATSG):

[image]

Anyone have an idea?

EDIT:

In reply to a question, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This aws answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241830) says that you can't change the security group on the network ENI which it looks like you're trying to change from the first image. The documentation you provided is for a nat instance. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish you can attach the security group to application instances or create a NAT instance and attach it to that?

Comment: I'll get back to you after the weekend, thanks in advance. In the meantime, I've EDITED my post to show you what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically I wan't my Docker containerized microservices to be able to both communicate with eachother (bidrectionally) and with the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you. It seems to me like the amazon coworker just contradicts the official documentation?


Yes, the documentation I provided is for a NAT instance. It creates a security group for that instance, but it doesn't specify how to attach it. If not to the network interface of that instance, than to what do I attach the security group?

Comment: doc actuality vs reality on a lot of platforms can be misleading. That aside, I think you need to attach your security groups to a network interface instead of the nat gateway. In order of creation I think it goes subnet -> nat gateway -> security group -> network interface -> attach network interface to nat gateway -> profit? Admittedly I don't create these manually. I use terraform created from this awesome resource: https://github.com/segmentio/stack The stack sounds similar to what you're trying to accomplish I suggest reading it through

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've decided to step away from ECS though. I'm using Docker Swarm which is working just fine for me.